# c# Replace pattern with external string utilizing wildcard subexpression as key

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string which contains various tags such as , I need to replace the entire matched string with the contents of the filename indicated, keeping in mind that the filename is not actually known so it cannot be directly searched for.

I get most of it, but what's hanging me up is how to use the subexpression outside a normal replace but instead as an argument to a method to return the passed files contents.

```
page= Regex.Replace(page,"<!--Include:(.*)-->",getFileContents($1));
```

The $1 is what's hanging me up because I cannot get the subexpression out like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you are not looking for String.Replace()

Comment: String.Replace() does not offer the pattern matching and subexpressions I need. If the exact string I was looking to replace was known then yes this would work, but as the string im searching for is in itself unknown I must use the RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Regex.Replace's overload which takes `MatchEvaluator`

```
page= Regex.Replace(page,"<!--Include:(.*)-->", 
                    m => getFileContents(m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: It looks like you get what im asking, the above code returns "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type" and I'm not sure what part of that made it think I was trying to cast to int.

Comment: @Wobbles without knowing your code, it is nearly imposible where your bug is. But above code has the correct syntax and I tested it before posting.

Comment: I'm just using the code you posted pretty much `page = Regex.Replace(page, "<!--Include:(.*)-->", m => Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value));`

Comment: i'm a moron, the non string return of Console.Write threw it off in my test, works great thanks!

Comment: can I nest subexpressions to make it untouched if say the file does not exist? for example: `page = Regex.Replace(page, "(<!--Include:(.*)-->)", string.isnull(Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value))?"$1":m => Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value));`?